# How To Create D3 Geographic Projection with SVG (Instead of JSON Data)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geo

**I'm trying to create map projections using D3, utilizing custom SVGs (inline or imported) instead of JSON data.** My end goal is to be able to take a geographic SVG created in illustrator or another program and project it multiple ways (mercator projection, various orthographic globe views, etc.) and allow some level of interaction, rotation, and zooming. The trouble is all the D3 examples I can scrounge up presume you're starting with JSON data, which I am not.

If needed, I suppose converting the custom SVGs into JSON would be acceptable, though I'm not aware of a method of doing that that maintains fidelity and isn't cumbersome.

Anyone have a basic outline for how to accomplish this SVG projection? If it helps, here are a couple examples of how the end result could appear:

- http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4686432
- https://observablehq.com/@d3/versor-dragging
- Really good example of a globe with projection and interactivity: https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/

FYI – The SVGs I'm immediately interested in turning into D3 geoprojections would be custom SVGs of Mars and Venus and various solar system moons. Though I want the process to apply to projecting any SVG really.

I can follow and modify the examples I find using the JSON data, but I'm not versed enough to figure out how to start with SVG. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the projection used to create the SVG? Preferably the SVG would only consist of paths - and preferably paths without arcs/curves. Can you describe the types of elements in the SVG, or share an example?

Comment: Well, it would be SVGs without embedded images or anything. Most any SVG illustration would do as a demonstration. This is an example of a simple map SVG: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:World_map_-_low_resolution.svg. I don't have any particular projection in mind as an initial projection. I'm asking a more general-purpose approach, so I suppose converting between projections would be part of it?

Comment: If you can share that file's projection parameters, I think I can give you an answer. We can only reproject from a projection we know.

Comment: I don't really have any specific file (the mars/venus stuff doesn't exist yet, I will make it). I'd like a general-purpose approach. You could think of it as anything you'd like, even projecting a smiley face SVG onto a globe. You can assume the smiley face starts in Robinson or Mercator or whatever projection you think appropriate. 

The core of my inquiry is: How do I replace the JSON data component in the D3 examples I've found with an already-existing SVG?

Comment: I think we're still not on the same page. My question was *what projection was used to make the SVG you shared*? We have to deproject it first, then reproject it. That has to be the first step, otherwise you won't have the end result you want. For a smiley face, something not geographic, then we can take a lot of liberties, the result isn't supposed to align anywhere. With geographic features we need to know the relationship between the already existing image's coordinates and geographic locations before we do anything like create json or a new image with a new/multiple projection(s).

Comment: If you have an image which you can specify the projection for (including extent), then I can write an answer showing how to convert the coordinates into json for projection into an arbitrary projection (if the SVG is like the one you shared). If the initial projection is unknown, you cannot reproject into an arbitrary projection.

Comment: Ah. My apologies for not understanding earlier. So you necessarily have to convert the SVG into JSON data to work with D3? I had presumed there would be a method of bypassing JSON completely. The ideal would be taking an inline SVG and then using D3 to project it into whatever geographic projection we wanted. It can't work that way?

Comment: @AndrewReid

How about this to use as an example:
– SVG of the USA: https://mapsvg.com/maps/usa. 
– Presume the projection is Mercator
– Project as if the USA was the only landmass on Earth.
– USA SVG is in the same position and coordinates as the real USA. 

Does this work?

Comment: D3 geoPaths only work with geojson, and D3-geoProjection assumes that the input coordinates are WGS84 lat long pairs. The SVG has coordinates in pixels, which we need to convert into WGS84 lat long pairs to be able to project them (other projection libraries can move from projection A coordinate space to projection B coordinate space directly, but you still need to know both A and B, always).

Comment: Using your US example, we will assume that the USA SVG is a Mercator, which in projected units covers a 960x960 pixel area with the center at [~297,~159] pixels and aligning with [0,0] on earth, with a northern/southern limit of roughly 85 degrees. We then extract the vertices from the SVG, unproject them to get a lat long, and then create geojson from that, then we project it. [eg](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/6e0d460507e0be27dbc209cc363341ec), but as the 1st projection has no relation to the data source, Alaska occupies most of a hemisphere, the rest of the US is around the south pole.

Comment: @AndrewReid I can see Alaska, though I'm not sure I understand why it's taking up about half the world. I tried editing your code...removing Alaska and Hawaii form the inline SVG. But what I end up with after the re-projection is a few badly distorted shapes looking nothing like the USA. I tried various rotations of the newProjection variable, but no luck. Definitely not achieving the goal of having the USA placed appropriately on the Orthographic projection. Do you know what's going wrong?

Comment: We don't know what projection the source data uses and chose one arbitrarily. "USA SVG is in the same position and coordinates as the real USA." - this isn't true - the SVG uses a non-geographic coordinate system (pixels), without knowing the projection used to create the SVG we cannot know what pixel in the source SVG corresponds to what latitude/longitude on Earth; therefore we cannot reproject it accurately to a new SVG.